# How to execute gmake/make from a bash script file?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make, freebsd

I'd like to execute my Makefile from a bash script file using make/gmake depending on the system it is being compiled on: gmake on FreeBSD (not the standard make) and make on others. For that I would like to determine if the make command installed on the system is GNU make:
 - if GNU make then compile with make
 - if not GNU make then compile with gmake (and raise error if gmake is not installed)

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if make --version | grep "^GNU Make" >& /dev/null
then
  MAKE=make
else
  MAKE=gmake
fi

${MAKE} ...
```

EDIT: Changed --ver to --version

Comment: This relies on --version being available, which I believe is a new addition to GNU make (according to the documentation). Is there an alternative (I mean more robust) way of checking this?

Comment: No, this addition is not so new. For example look at http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2000-09/msg00028.html ; this patch is 12 years old, but it relies on `--version`

Comment: Right, it didn't work on Solaris but it turned out the default make wasn't GNU make anyway. This simple solution should be suitable for my needs. Thanks!

Comment: On Linux doesn't work: make: option '--ver' is ambiguous; possibilities: '--version' '--verbosity'

Comment: @uzsolt: thank you for the tip! (the answer is fixed, thanks to amiramix)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `uname`:

```
if [ `uname -s` = "FreeBSD" ]; then
    makeprg=gmake
else
    makeprg=make
fi
```

As I see on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname) on FreeBSD `uname -s` will print FreeBSD and on Linux will the output Linux (on my machine too).

Edit: FreeBSD instead of Linux.

Comment: That's not a bad approach but assumes it will be compiled with gmake on all non-Linux systems, which probably isn't the case. I would probably still prefer Igor's approach which doesn't have any implicit assumptions which type of make runs on which system. Otherwise would be probably as good.

Comment: You can change the "Linux" to "FreeBSD" and replace 'make' and 'gmake' (so on FreeBSD use 'gmake', on any other system 'make'). I was inattentive about your question :)

Comment: Yes, agreed, but still doesn't seem universal enough. Would there be any system reporting "Linux" from uname not using GNU make as default? I can't answer that question (seems safe), which is why testing the output of make looks a bit more resilient. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Check my edit! This is what you want: "gmake on FreeBSD (not the standard make) and make on others".

Comment: What I want is to determine if 'make' is a GNU-compatible make, not if I am running FreeBSD or Linux. This is why the first answer is better in my case. Of course, Linux usually runs gnu make and FreeBSD usually doesn't, but checking the output of make seems to be more suitable in this case.